# Master Detail Null Reference Exception

Tags: c#, asp.net

Loking for your insight as to why I'm getting this error, actually better yet, how to fix it. I have a nested gridview inside gridview. There may be a better way but at this point I've got the modal popup to work which also took forever, so unless this is completely stupid way to display master-detail then say so now.

I am able to pass the datakey id to the detail grid but that is where I get the null reference exception, I guess the bugger doesen't exist yet, or is not visible. I mean, what-ever-the-reason is, how do I fix this? Thanks in advace.

aspx file:

```
<asp:Content ID="Content1" ContentPlaceHolderID="ContentPlaceHolder1" Runat="Server">
    <asp:GridView ID="gvForum" runat="server" DataSourceID="odsForumApproval" DataKeyNames="id" Width="200px" 
      RepeatColumns="1" DataKeyField="id"  CssClass="gridview"
      AutoGenerateColumns="False" GridLines="None"  OnSelectedIndexChanged="_OnCommand">
      <AlternatingRowStyle CssClass="altbgcolor"  />
      <Columns>   
      <asp:TemplateField >
      <ItemTemplate>
      <asp:Label runat="server" ID="lblTitle" Text='<%# Bind("Title") %>' />                                

      <asp:Panel id="div" runat="server" align="center" class="confirm" style="display:none"  >
      <asp:GridView runat="server" ID="gvForumDetail" AutoGenerateColumns="False" DataKeyNames="id"
      EmptyDataText="No Forum Detail"  AllowPaging='true'
      AllowSorting="true" PageSize="5"  >
      <AlternatingRowStyle CssClass="altbgcolor" />
      <RowStyle VerticalAlign="Top" HorizontalAlign="Left" />
      <Columns>
        <asp:TemplateField>
          <ItemTemplate>
            <asp:Label runat="server" ID="lblTraining" Text='<%# Bind("title") %>' />
          </ItemTemplate>
        </asp:TemplateField>
        <asp:TemplateField>
          <ItemTemplate>
            <asp:Label runat="server" ID="lblCompletionDate" Text='<%# Bind("description") %>' />
          </ItemTemplate>
        </asp:TemplateField>
        <asp:TemplateField>
          <ItemTemplate>
            <asp:Label runat="server" ID="lblRecurence" Text='<%# Bind("MemberName") %>' />
          </ItemTemplate>
        </asp:TemplateField>
        <asp:TemplateField>
          <ItemTemplate>
            <asp:Label runat="server" ID="lblNotes" Text='<%# Bind("itemdate") %>' Width="200" />
          </ItemTemplate>
        </asp:TemplateField>
        <asp:CommandField ShowCancelButton="true" ShowEditButton="true" ShowDeleteButton="true" />
      </Columns>
      </asp:GridView>                               
      <br />
      <asp:Button ID="btnClose" runat="server" Text="Close" Width="50px" />                               
      </asp:Panel>   

      <ajaxToolKit:ModalPopupExtender ID="ModalPopupExtender1" runat="server"                                        
      TargetControlID="lblTitle" 
      PopupControlID="div" 
      CancelControlID="btnClose"  
      BackgroundCssClass="modalBackground" />

      </ItemTemplate>
      </asp:TemplateField>
      <asp:CommandField ShowSelectButton="True" ShowDeleteButton="true" />
      </Columns> 
      </asp:GridView>
```

code file:

```
public void _OnCommand(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    ObjectDataSource ods = new ObjectDataSource();
    ods.ID = "ods_ForumDetail";
    ods.EnableViewState = true;
    ods.TypeName = "Forum";
    ods.SelectMethod = "GetForumPostByID";

    string id = "";
    int rowIndex = gvForum.SelectedIndex;
    id = gvForum.DataKeys[rowIndex].Value.ToString();
    ods.SelectParameters.Add("id", System.TypeCode.Int32, id);

    GridView gvForumDetail = (GridView)Master.FindControl("ContentPlaceHolder1").FindControl("gvForum").FindControl("gvForumDetail");
    gvForumDetail.DataSource = ods;
    gvForumDetail.DataBind();
}
```

Comment: What line are you getting the error on?

Comment: gvForumDetail.DataSource = ods;

Comment: Also I realy don't care about my "rating" on this forum, but I'm courious as to how did my post scored a negative 2 and that my question "does't show any reserch effort". You people kidding right? WTF!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You haven't told where exactly you get the null-reference-exception.
But why are you going this indirect way via MasterPage to find your Detail-Grid?

The direct way is much easier and above all less error-prone:

```
var gvForum = (GridView)sender;
var gvForumDetail = (GridView)(gvForum.SelectedRow.FindControl("gvForumDetail"));
```

Apart from that, your approach to find the nested GridView can never work. [FindControl](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/486wc64h.aspx) will only search the current [NamingContainer](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.control.namingcontainer.aspx) for the given ID. Hence following might work, but is hardlinking the Master with one of it's ContentPages what is always bad:

```
(GridView)Master.FindControl("ContentPlaceHolder1").FindControl("gvForum");
```

But this will not lead you to your nested GridView since...

```
gvForum.FindControl("gvForumDetail");
```

...will not search all GridViewRows in the GridView for `gvForumDetail` but only the NamingContainer of the GridView itself. A GridViewRow has it's own NamingContainer(to enable to use same ID's in ItemTemplate although multiple rows exist), so the only correct approach is to get the current SelectedRow and search there your nested Grid(see above).

You haven't yet shown where you `DataBind` your nested GridView. That should be done in [RowDataBound](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.webcontrols.gridview.rowdatabound.aspx) of the outer GridView. That might be the reason why it's null.
Another reason for getting a NullRefernceException might be that you are possibly DataBinding your outer GridView on every postback in page_load instead of only `if(!IsPostBack)`. That would deselect your Grid which causes `SelectedRow` to be nothing in my approach.

Comment: I've tried that and get the same result. Error is on gvForumDetail.DataSource = ods.

Comment: @Risho: Updated my answer. Btw, i haven't downvoted you, although you should have added more details.

Comment: I've ended up trying your initial example and it worked. I'm not sure what more should I have added as far as detail. What I pasted is pretty much the meat of the code.

Comment: @Risho: Sometimes you know only what details are helpful _after_ you know the solution ;) Therefor i've added some situations that possibly cause issues like yours. Glad to hear that it works now.

Comment: The nested gridview is populated with the _onCommand event, and it is pasted in my original post.

Answer (score 0):

Here is a simple walkthrough on how to do nested gridviews. [Link](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa992038%28v=vs.80%29.aspx)

I agree with Tim, you are doing some odd things.  I would also declaratively create your objectdatasource in HTML so you dont have to create it dynamically every command.

**Update**
Here is another [Link](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Qc53ZekBryE) This is a video to show you step by step how to do what you want and pass the select parameters to your inner gridview. (about 3:40).

Comment: OK, I gave up arguing with the community about creating ods in html as I my oppion it "violates" the n-tier architecture, besides I can never get it working like in this instance. How do I pass id from the master grid to the detail grid when you use ods in html????

Comment: I added another link.  this is a video of how to do what you are wanting to do.  If you wanted to skip to about 3:44 you will see how to pass your parameters from the outer grid to the inner grid.

Comment: Thank yor your time and effort, the links are inded useful.